# swagger-codegen on linux, installation problem

Tags: homebrew, swagger-codegen

I am trying to install swagger-codegen, my java version is 11 and I did it installing homebrew as it is done in mac since no linux information wa found, I used the instructions on the documentation :
[enter link description here](https://brew.sh/)

After installing it I try to install swagger-codegen:
`brew install swagger-codegen`

all this is done on the folde where I installed homebrew:
`home/linuxbrew/homebrew`

once this is done I go to my project and try to run the swagger-codegen comand to generrate the api docs:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l ruby -o /tmp/test/
```

the result is

```
bash: swagger-codegen: command not found
```

basically it is not installed apparently, I dont know what is the problem, is there any other way to install swagger-codegen in linux?, does anyone knows what is the issue here?

thanks in advance

Comment: FYI. Many top contributors of Swagger Codegen are now working on OpenAPI Generator instead, which comes with a NPM CLI wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli. You may give it a try to see if it better meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

basically a computer reset after installing everything was enought to make things work again